# difference between "уже не" and "больше"

Tags: выражения, разница

What's the difference between
Я больше не люблю тебя - I don't love you anymore

я уже не люблю тебя- I don't love you anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically they mean the same thing. However *Я больше не люблю тебя* is often used when one person stopped loving another person as a consequence of some circumstances or actions that happened immediately or at some point before the speech.

> Ты изменил мне и поэтому я больше не люблю тебя - You cheated on me
> and so I don't love you anymore.

People would unlikely say *Ты изменил мне и поэтому я **уже** не люблю тебя*. So people use the *больше не люблю тебя* phrase when they are reacting to something that made them stop loving, while they may use *я уже не люблю тебя*, when love is gone but nothing particular happened to move lovers apart.

Answer (score 2):

"Больше не" means "not anymore", "not any longer"

"Уже не" means "[my] need is past due"

"больше не"/"уже не" are both frequently used with "хотеть" (want), but it's almost always "больше не" with "любить" (love).

Compare:

- "Я больше не хочу пить" - "I don't want to drink any more", which typically means "I had drunk enough already"
- "Я уже не хочу пить" which is close to the above, but usually means "My thirst is just gone"

With "love":

- "Я больше не люблю тебя" - "I don't love you anymore" (no comments)
- "Я уже не люблю тебя" - rarely used. It implies that the feelings weren't reciprocal, and the previously rejected lover now got over his/her feelings.